# Please, do I need to protect password before entry into my server provider mysql

Tags: php, database, security

I am currently designing a small social community site before I came across **"password hashing"** when I was researching. I hosted the site on a hosting site, so, I don't know if it's my job to protect my users' passwords or it is their job to secure their databases. Please if you don't understand my question, ask so that I can explain it.

Comment: You have to read Terms of Service (and you will see that is your job...)

Comment: @fusion3k, is it that they don't provide any protection, so I might likely be vulnerable to the hosting-provider  attacks too?

Comment: I think that it provide some protection. You can discover it reading your hosting plain features and Terms of Service. BTW is your script is vulnerable (to SQL injections, i.e.) your data will be vulnerable, independently of hosting features. Hashing passwords and using prepared statements is always a good choice.

Comment: @fusion3k, thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: both.

It is both their job and your job to secure the database. You should plan for one or both of you failing at this.

### Access control

Your job in securing the database starts with what you can manage: the credentials that you use, both for you and the application you are making.

Everything that gives any kind of "privileged access" should be set up to require a login, and that should involve a strong password (I recommend using random password generators and/or a password manager). This may include but is not limited to:

- The database login, both for you and your application
- FTP
- SSH (consider looking into key based authentication for this)
- Admin accounts on the website you're building

The database should require a password to be connected to, and that password should be strong (I recommend a random password generator for this). The same goes for all logins you have for the server itself, which may include things like FTP and SSH, and also for any logins to the application (such as an admin account) you're building, other applications such as PHP My Admin.

### Application security

Your role as the application developer is to secure the application that contacts the database. From the point of view of securing the database, you are most worried about SQL injection. You mention you are already familiar with this so I'll skip the basics.

**Strongly consider using parameterized queries or an ORM.**

If you rely on escaping parameters every time you write a query, you need to make zero mistakes for the database to be secure. A single mistake could have serious consequences.

Using parameterized queries or an ORM can take care of this for you, so you don't need to worry about it, and are less likely to have SQL injection vulnerabilities as a result.

You will also need to follow other best security practices when building the application - for example, remote code execution vulnerabilities are likely to result in database access even if no SQL injection vulnerabilities are present.

### Planning for a breach anyway

Given how common SQL injection vulnerabilities are, it's best practice to try to mitigate their consequences as much as possible. This is where password hashing comes into it.

A brief summary: The objective is to make it very time consuming for an attacker to determine passwords given the data stored in your database. The best options for this are things like bcrypt and scrypt. You want something that is secure, very well scrutizined, and in particular: slow.

Avoid fast things such as MD5 and the SHA family.

### Appendix: If you manage the database server

In a shared hosting arrangement, the host is running the database server for you. If you're managing it - for example, if you had to download and install the database server application - then you have some extra work to do.

You need to keep the software for the database - and in fact all software on the server, including the operating system - up to date to ensure that you have the latest security patches.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a popular hosting site, like godaddy.com for instance, they do provide protection, but that only matters if you yourself are writing code that is "secure". For instance, if your code that accesses the database that stores the passwords allows for sql injection, then you would have made a backdoor for hackers to use, regardless of how unhackable the hosting site is itself.

Your question is broad and we don't have much specifics to base our answers on.

Comment: I am using a local hosting site smartweb.com. And I have tried to prevent injection through a lot of posts and answers I've found on this site. Like escaping inputs, quoting, escaping with mysqli_real_escape_string and all that. So, I think my code is secure. Thanks for your tip even though my rating is low.

Comment: @Stephinext I would also recommend using `htmlspecialchars()` It's probably the best function for preventing sql injection out there.